# AngularJS: How to get changed key and value from existing object in form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular1.6

I've an object which contains 100 keys, value pairs.

```
$scope.obj = {
  key1: value1,
  key1: value1,
  .
  .
  .
  key100: value100
}
```

I have 100 inputs

```
<form>
   <input value="obj.key1" ng-model="obj.key1" />
   <input value="obj.key2" ng-model="obj.key2" />
   <input value="obj.key3" ng-model="obj.key3" />
   .
   .
   .
   <input value="obj.key100" ng-model="obj.key100" />
   <button ng-click="submit> </button>
</form>
```

When I sumbit the data will send to server. Some time I'll change values and  sometimes not. If I change a value in one input I want that `key,value` from object. So that I can send server call with that data not to send entire data.

Comment: @Satpal My intension is to get perticular change key value pair in Object.

Comment: May i know how will you change the value will you be having a text box to re-edit the value or are you changing in code?

Comment: @Kannan Re edit

Answer (score 1):

I would achieve this by using the default `ngForm` directives like `$dirty` and a "save state" object of your original input values. This is a easy solution to achieve what you want. `ngForm` itself does not provide the original values so you have to create a "save object" and compare them manually.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" name="key1" ng-model="obj.key1"><br />
    <input type="text" name="key2" ng-model="obj.key2"><br />
    <input type="text" name="key3" ng-model="obj.key3">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.obj = {
      key1: 'test 1',
      key2: 'test 2',
      key3: 'test 3',
    }

    var originalValues = angular.copy($scope.obj);

    $scope.submit = function () {

      var paramsChanged = {};

      angular.forEach($scope.obj, function (value, key) {
          if ($scope.myForm[key].$dirty && originalValues[key] !== value) {
            paramsChanged[key] = value;
          }
      });

      console.log(paramsChanged);
    }
});
```

**> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4dv1akq/)**

Comment: If i have nested Objects. Your solution will not work and it is not working when i change more than one value. it always returning last edited only

Comment: @Mr.Pandya also with nested objects it will work with a small code change. But if you got nested object, why don't you add them to your question? There is no information about "nested" object inside your question. How should we help you with that if we don't know about your full requirements? In your question you told us that you just have a `key,value` object.

Comment: @Mr.Pandya I modified the solution. There was a small error in it. Now it will collect all changed values not even the last one.

Comment: @lin -- How is this different from my solution, except that you're checking `$dirty` flag?

Answer (score 0):

Have a copy of the variable and just before sending it to the server, compare the model object with the copied variable using a compare function like the following:

```
// At the time of initialization
$scope.obj = [ ... ];
var copiedObj = angular.copy($scope.obj);

// At the time of submit
var changed = {};

Object.keys(copiedObj).forEach(key => {
  if(copiedObj[key] !== $scope.obj[key]) {
    changed[key] = $scope.obj[key];
  }
});

// Submit `changed` to the server
```

Assuming `copiedObj` is the copy of original `$scope.obj`, `changed` will contain the keys which are actually changed. So you can send `changed` to the server.

Comment: I want thae value without interating keys

Comment: @Mr.Pandya -- that will be worse. You will need to watch the variable, and even for a single change the watch's callback will be fired. See Jim Wright's answer for that.

Comment: Is there any better solution

Comment: @Mr.Pandya -- what's wrong in iterating over the keys? This is faster and an elegant solution to your problem.

Comment: For now it is 100. If I have 1000 inputs. It takes time

Comment: @Mr.Pandya -- Your problem has limited solutions, I'm afraid.

Comment: Can I split all inputs to different form and send data by comparing

Comment: @Mr.Pandya You said you never wanted to iterate then how will you compare

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) to watch for specific changes in `$scope`.

```
$scope.$watch('obj.key1', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log('Key1 was updated from' + oldValue + ' to ' + newValue');
});
```

Comment: Not like this. THanks

Comment: You've rejected watching individual properties, and looping over the object. What else is there?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way have a ng-change bind to your HTML and whenever the ng-change happens for a particular Element write a code to push into an array and send that array to the server.
A sample Code

```
    <input value="obj.key100" ng-model="obj.key100" ng-change="selectedValue(obj.keyx)" />
```

Angular Code

```
 $scope.tempValues=[];
 $scope.selectedValue = function(x) {
    $scope.tempValues.push(x);
 }
```

Comment: What happens when a key is changed and reset again to the original value?

Comment: Then in that case we need to compare with existing value only by having a IF condition OP doesn't want to iterate each elements so i had to go for this logic

Comment: @Kannan. Initially my input value is 'kannan'. I removed 'n'. Then I added 'n'. FInally result is 'Kannan'. This time your condition fails.

Comment: Yes @Mr.Pandya but you don't want to iterate nor use $watch then what other options is there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-change` to detect any changes, as well as a (key, value) syntax in `ng-repeat` to list your inputs. Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.obj = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
  }

  var toSend = [];
  $scope.select = function(key) {
    var s = {};
    s[key] = $scope.obj[key]
    toSend.push(s); // or just the value: $scope.obj[key]
  }

  $scope.submit = function() {
    console.log(toSend)
    $scope.sent = toSend;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <form ng-submit="submit()">
    <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in obj">
      <input ng-change="select(key)" ng-model="value" /><br>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>

  <pre>{{sent | json}}</pre>

</div>
```

Comment: What happens when a key is changed and reset again to the original value?